# Binding toggle() code to JS-generated element

Tags: jquery

Generally speaking I know to attach code to a JS-generated element, but when `toggle()` is involved I can't make it work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).on('toggle', '.header_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children a', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').fadeIn(0);
  return false;
},
function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').fadeOut(0);
  return false;
});
```

This code fails to fire (clicking on the element targetted doesn't run the code specified here). Why?

Comment: use `click` instead of toggle. there is no event listener for `toggle`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. That's not the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no demo that I could fork and try my code out, here is my 2 cents and hopefully working code snippet.

As far as I'm aware the jQuery .on only has one callback, which is the issue here.

How you could solve this: on each click of the element check the visibility of the submenu and toggle it accordingly.

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.header_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children a', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var $subMenu = $(this).siblings('.sub-menu');
  var visible  = $subMenu.is(':visible');

  if( visible ) $subMenu.fadeOut(0);
  else $subMenu.fadeIn(0);

});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, awesome :)